# How to push an object array using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to push an array of objects and save changes using in-memory objects instead of `$push` command but it only accepts a single ObjectId. Is there a way of doing it? My goal is efficiency as I've got the database object in memory already.

The Schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const planejamentoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "users",
  },
  dia: Date,
  receitas: [
    {
      _id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "receitas",
      },
      nome: String,
      refeicao: String,
    },
  ],
});

const Planejamentos = mongoose.model("planejamentos", planejamentoSchema);

module.exports = Planejamentos;
```

The route with $push

```
router.post("/", tokenValidation.checkToken, (req, res) => {
  let user = req.body.user;
  let dia = req.body.dia;

  const query = { user, dia };

  Planejamentos.findOne(query).exec((err, result) => {
      // AS YOU CAN SEE, I'VE GOT TO QUERY IT AGAIN 
      // INSTEAD OF JUST result.receitas.push(req.body.receitas)
      Planejamentos.updateMany(
        query,
        {
          $push: {
            receitas: { $each: req.body.receitas },
          },
        },
        (err, result) => {
            res.send(
              `Planejamento para ${query.user} em ${query.dia} atualizado com sucesso`
            );
        }
      );
  });
});
```

Comment: I think using `$push` is still your best shot as it ensures an atomic update to your `Planejamentos` document. If you were to update the array in memory, you would still have to execute a `.save()` on the model to ensure that the update gets saved to the database. So either way, you still have to make a trip down to the database.

Comment: Provided you only intend to update the document returned from the `.findOne` query, you can make the update query faster by calling `update` directly on the result of the `.findOne`, i.e something like`result.update({ $push: { ... } })` as opposed to the `.updateMany` you currently have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using `$push` is still your best shot as it ensures an atomic update to your `Planejamentos` document. If you were to update the array in memory, you would still have to execute a `.save()` on the model to ensure that the update gets saved to the database. So either way, you still have to make a trip down to the database.

Provided you only intend to update the document returned from the `.findOne` query, you can make the update query faster by calling update directly on the result of the `.findOne`, i.e something like:

```
// ... 
Planejamentos.findOne(query).exec((err, result) => {
  // Call .update on the result directly
  result.update(
    {
      $push: {
        receitas: { $each: req.body.receitas },
      },
    },
    (udpateError, updateResult) => {
      res.send(
        `Planejamento para ${query.user} em ${query.dia} atualizado com sucesso`
      )
    }
  )
})
// ...
```

as opposed to the `.updateMany` you currently have.

**EDIT**
Alternatively, if you have some validation or middleware logic on the `Planejamentos` model, then, you should update the array in memory and then execute a `.save`. Note that you are still making the trip to the database, in fact, internally mongoose would translate your update to the array to something like this:

```
updateOne({ _id: <doc>._id }, { $push: { '$each': <Array update value> } } })
```

But then, this approach would allow the execution of the validation and middleware logic associated with the model. More details [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html#updating).

If you don't have any middleware or validation in place, you need not worry about this.